# Populate dropdown list when dropdown is displayed ?

Tags: jquery

First of all I want to say I'm very new to jQuery, I just started yesterday so I'm kinda fuzzy on some of the logic, don't hesitate to correct me if I'm not using the best pratices.

Basically what I want to do is :

- I have a webpage with a few buttons
- when I click on one of the button, I will load a div containing a few elements (that differs depending on the button pressed)
- in some of these cases there's a dropdown list that I want to populate with ajax when it's loaded

I can handle the buttons and the div loading correctly, but I'm having a bit of trouble with my dropdown list. I want to do the ajax call when the dropdown is loaded in the document, and I can't figure out how to do that.

A little bit of HTML that is created when I click one of the button :

```
<div class='content'>
  <select class='dropdown'></select>
</div>
```

This is only added to the document AFTER I clicked on a button, it's not there in the first place (basically because different buttons will load different stuff in the content div)

What I first tried in my JS :

```
$('select.dropdown').load(function() {
   alert('dropdown loaded');
});
```

This didn't work, at all, the alert never appeared no matter where I put this little bit of JS (I tried putting it before creating the select in html, I tried putting it after, no matter what I never got the alert)

So I tried with the ready function :

```
$('select.dropdown').ready(function() {
  alert('dropdown loaded');
});
```

And that worked. I replaced the alert with a .post() looking like this :

```
$('select.dropdown').ready(function() {
  $.post("url.php", {arg: 'arg'}, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      $('select.dropdown').append("html stuff with <option>");
    });
  }, 'json');
```

And that worked well. But the thing is, now I want to populated only the select tag that fired the .ready() event, so I tried with $(this) :

```
$('select.dropdown').ready(function() {
  $.post("url.php", {arg: 'arg'}, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      $(this).append("html stuff with <option>");
    });
  }, 'json');
```

And that didn't work. If I try adding an alert to see what "this" is referencing :

```
$('select.dropdown').ready(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
  $.post("url.php", {arg: 'arg'}, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      $(this).append("html stuff with <option>");
    });
  }, 'json');
```

I get "undefined".

So basically my questions are :

- Why the .ready() works and not the .load() ?
- How can I use $(this) in a .ready() function to reference the dropdown that fired the ready event ?

The reason I want to use $(this) and not the first solution is because I will dynamically add other dropdown, that will use the same HTML markup and the same JS code (if possible), so I have to discriminate which dropdown fired the ready event.

Any ideas/advices on how to do that ?

Comment: I have never seen the .ready() applied to an element, only the document.  My understanding is that it is triggered when the DOM is "ready", meaning it has been loaded completely.  The load() is called when the document is loaded, but prior to the ready() as CSS and such may not have been applied.  I may be completely wrong about this, though.  One question I have is if you are creating the select dynamically, or does it already exist on the page?

Comment: I thought .ready() applied to any elements, but it appears you're right, and that explains why my $(this) doesn't work properly.
As for the select it is created dynamically, and I can't figure when or how I'm supposed to bind the .load() function for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot attach the options at creation as another poster suggests then perhaps you could use a custom event:

```
$('#mybuttonid').click(function(){
    //load whatever here
    $('select.dropdown').trigger('dropReady');//change selector to get right one
});
$(document).on('dropReady','select.dropdown',function(){
    //do what you need
});
```

NOTE try to use a wrapper and not document for the anchor event.

Comment: Thx, that did the trick !
I actually put the event directly on the dropdown, I don't know if it's a good idea or not, but it works.

Comment: @user2393628 - as you are new here on SO, you can "accept" an answer by using the checkmark to the left the the answer that best resoles your issue by clicking that.

Comment: as long as the "wrapper" - document in this case, exists when you create the event manager with the `on` you should be OK - otherwise, it has nothing to attach to and will not be created as an event manager.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you cannot populate the dropdown prior to painting it? It would be much easier to chain the events that way. That would be the easiest option.

Failing that, you could use `.each` callback on the `append` or `appendTo` events to populate the dropdown once it has been added to the DOM. You didn't provide that code snippet, so I've made a few assumptions with this one.

Example:

```
var content = $("<div class='content'>").appendTo(body);

$("<select class='dropdown'></select>")
.appendTo(content).each(function() {
  $.post("url.php", {arg: 'arg'}, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      $(this).append("<option>");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The only reason I didn't populate the dropdown before adding it to the DOM is because I didn't knew how. Like I said, I'm still at the beginning stages of learning jQuery, and I actually didn't knew that you can create a div (or whatever) in a variable and work on it before adding it to the DOM.
But still, even though that works in this case, I have a few other cases later on where I'll need to populate a dropdown after displaying it, so I still wanted to know how to do that. The other answer did the trick, but I'll try your solution too.